# Why is (commandp '(customize-option 'foo)) nil?

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

I want to bind `customize-option` for a certain variable to a key, since I need to change it rather often. I have two options:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<f12>") '(lambda() (interactive) (customize-option 'my-variable) ) )
(global-set-key (kbd "<f12>") '(customize-option 'my-variable )
```

The first one works, the second does not, because `commandp` complains that `customize-option` is not a command. Why? As far as I know, `customize-option` is an interactive function, so `commandp` should be `t`:

> customize-option is an interactive compiled Lisp function.
>
> It is bound to    .
>
> (customize-option SYMBOL)
>
> Customize SYMBOL, which must be a user option variable.

Comment: Please don't quote lambda expressions.  I.e. Use `(lambda ...)` rather than `'(lambda ...)`.  Both work, but adding the quote is a bad habit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the form `(customize-option 'my-variable)` which is not a command. You cannot bind to an arbitrary quoted form, any more than you can bind to a literal string or an unbound symbol. Some of those would be useful to bind to, but it's not hard to work around the limitations. Write a macro if you find it hard to live with. (As the saying goes, now you have two problems.)

Comment: Sounds good. What would the macro solution look like? Still bit of an elisp newbie...

Comment: In the simplest case, something like `(defmacro bind-to (key seq) (global-set-key ,key (function (lambda (nil) ,@seq)))` if my macro skills haven't rusted too badly. Macros can easily get you into heavy voodoo, though.

Comment: Ok, I think then that I can stick with my above solution. At least now I understand why I can't bind it without the lambda around it.

Answer (score 3):

The second argument to `global-set-key` must be a *command definition*, typically a symbol naming an interactive function. An interactive function is a function that begins with the `(interactive)` form. For example:

```
(defun delete-to-end ()
  "Delete text from point to the end of buffer."
  (interactive)
  (delete-region (point) (point-max)))
```

This defines an interactive function and assigns it to the symbol `delete-to-end`. After that, `delete-to-end` is a valid command that you can pass to `global-set-key`:

```
(global-set-key [f12] 'delete-to-end)
```

Without the `(interactive)` line, `delete-to-end` would still name a function callable from Lisp programs, but it would not be a "command". Since it is marked interactive, `(commandp 'delete-to-end)` returns true, and <kbd>M-x delete-to-end</kbd> works.

Interactive functions don't need to be bound to a symbol, they can be anonymous. Like any other anonymous functions, they are created using a `lambda` form, except that for commands it must also include `(interactive)`. Anonymous commands can be passed as the second argument to `global-set-key` without assigning them to a symbol, so the following definition is equivalent to the one above:

```
(global-set-key [f12]
                (lambda ()
                  "Delete text from point to the end of buffer."
                  (interactive)
                  (delete-region (point) (point-max))))
```

...except it's somewhat less readable, and looks uglier when inspected with <kbd>C-h c</kbd>
or <kbd>C-h k</kbd>.

In your case, the first call to `global-set-key` is given a valid command (a quoted `lambda` form is itself a valid function), but the second one isn't, it is given a two-element list that can neither be called nor satisfies the requirement of being marked "interactive".